# Несколько запросов ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Делаю чат, в него входит уведомление о новых сообщениях в шапке (отдельный файл header.php)

```
<script>  
    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "updates/topupdate.php",  
            cache: false,  
            success: function(html){  
                $("#message-chat").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
        
    }  
  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',5000);  
    });  
</script>
```

Работает корректно, передаёт запрос в обработчик и возвращает в нужный див.

А также необходимо обновлять информацию на самой странице чата, то есть периодически проверять на новые сообщения в БД и выводить их.

```
<script>  
    function show()  
    {  
        $.ajax({  
            url: "updates/chatupdate.php",  
            cache: false, 
            type: "POST",
            data : {'idtodb':'<?php echo $idtodb ?>'}, 
            success: function(html){  
                $("#messagess").html(html);  
            }  
        });  
        
    }  
  
    $(document).ready(function(){  
        show();  
        setInterval('show()',5000);  
    });
```

Без подключения шапки скрипт тоже работает корректно, но одновременно 2 эти скрипта не хотят работать. Пожалуйста, подскажите, желательно с примером, в чём проблема и как это можно решить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Две функции названы одинаково - это проблема почему они не работают одновременно

И назовите их так, чтобы они "говорили", что делают. "show" говорит о том, что что-то показать.... причём не ясно что

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло

Comment: Тогда можно ткнуть галочку рядом с ответом)